# Find the first Unique Non-anagram strings in array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, set, unique

I'm trying to find the first unique string in array ignoring all other anagrams for example :

let words = ['nap', 'teachers', 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era', 'hectares'];

output = nap teachers ear

or 
let words = ['rat', 'tar', 'art'];

output rat

I stuck here

```
let set = new Set();
let words = let words = ['nap', 'teachers', 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era', 'hectares']


let map = new Map();
for (let word of words) {
    let sorted = word.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''); 
    map.set(sorted, word);
    set.add(sorted)
}
let arr = Array.from(set)


for (let inx = 0; inx < words.length; inx++) {
    arr.push('0')
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(words);

function isAnagram(s1, s2){
    return s1.split("").sort().join("") === s2.split("").sort().join("");
  }

let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
       if ()
       result.push(words[i])

}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `Map` of `string: string` in which you only store the last anagram option, you can create a map of `string: [ string ]` in which you store all options.

Then, in the end, you can loop over all those entries and return the first element of each array:

```js
let set = new Set();
let words = ['nap', 'teachers', 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era', 'hectares']


let map = new Map();

for (let word of words) {
    let sorted = word.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
    if (!map.has(sorted)) map.set(sorted, []);
    set.add(sorted);
    
    map.get(sorted).push(word);
}

let arr = Array
  .from(set)
  .map(k => map.get(k)[0])
  

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the current position of the array "words" and then check the others one, this means you need to have a loop inside a loop, so your code should look like this:

```js
let set = new Set();
let words = ['nap', 'teachers', 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era', 'hectares']


let map = new Map();
for (let word of words) {
    let sorted = word.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''); 
    map.set(sorted, word);
    set.add(sorted)
}
let arr = Array.from(set)


for (let inx = 0; inx < words.length; inx++) {
    arr.push('0')
}
console.log(arr);
console.log(words);

function isAnagram(s1, s2){
 console.log("checking: " + s1 + " and " + s2);
    return s1.split("").sort().join("") === s2.split("").sort().join("");
  }

let result = [];
let anagram = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
 for(let j=i+1; j<words.length; j++){
   if (isAnagram(words[i], words[j])){
    anagram = true; 
    break; 
    console.log("Is anagram!");
   }
  }
 if(anagram)
    {
  //Before insert we will see if we have an anagram in the result array
  anagram = false;
  for(let z=0; z<result.length; z++)
     {
   //We will se if it exists in result
   if(isAnagram(words[i],result[z]))
         {
    anagram = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  if(!anagram)
        {
            result.push(words[i]);
   anagram = false;
  }

 }
  }
       

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user3297291 
I found even simpler variant

```
let words = ['nap', 'teachers', 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era', 'hectares']
const set = new Set();
const unique = [];

words.forEach((word) => {

 const sorted = word.split('').sort().join('');

 if (set.has(sorted)) {
   return;
 }
   unique.push(word);
   set.add(sorted);
 });

 print(unique.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation. :)

```
function aClean(arr) {
     var map = new Map();
     arr.map(item => {
         var key = item.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
         map.has(key) ? null : map.set(key, item)
     });
    return Array.from(map.values());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
let words = ['nap', 'teachers', 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era', 'hectares']

let map = new Map(
    words.reverse().map(word => {
        let sorted = word.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''); 
        return [sorted, word];
    })
);

console.log(Array.from(map.values())); // output: [ "teachers", "ear", "nap" ]
```

Using the characters from each word as a key. Exemple: for [teacher, cheaters, hectares] the key is "aceehrst"

and since the order is important for finding the first one, reversing the order of words will help to keep "teacher" as a value for the key "aceehrst" instead of "hectares".

Comment: 1) it is not Javascript
2) this will never work as should, except the case where you provide very specific input (like one above) 

Summary: you are not solving the problem, you are providing code, that somehow outputs what correct code should output (in just one case btw.)

Comment: 1) my bad, fixed now.

Comment: 2) this work for two case btw. You can try the words = ['rat', 'tar', 'art'];

Comment: And since the code was already provided, i've just gave him a little help.